# Node pre 'save' hook using a statics function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, cryptography

I'm trying to use a custom encrypt function inside a pre 'save' hook on my schema, but i'm having an error telling me that this.encrypt is not a function

```
passwordSchema.pre('save', async function() {
    if (this.isModified('password')) {
        try {
            this.password = this.encrypt(this.password);
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('Error while encrypting the password : ' + error.message);
        }
    }

    if (this.isModified('login')) {
        try {
            this.login = passwordSchema.encrypt(this.login);
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('Error while encrypting the login : ' + error.message);
        }
    }
});
```

There is the function encrypt :

```
passwordSchema.statics.encrypt = function(password) {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', CRYPTO_AES);

    let encryptedPassword = cipher.update(password, 'utf8', 'hex');

    encryptedPassword += cipher.final('hex');

    return encryptedPassword;
};
```

And there is the schema :

```
const passwordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    login: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Login required"]
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Password required"]
    },

    commentaire: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

Note : The schema password is not exported at the end but instead used inside a collection schema

```
const collectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        [...],

        passwords: [passwordSchema]
    },

    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);
```

I have tried to use the constructor and other thing like "Password.encrypt" what can i do to be able to use this statics function inside the pre 'save' hook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`statics`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics) is used to generate static methods on the model.
You should try to use [`methods`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) to define instance functions:

```
passwordSchema.methods.encrypt = function(password) { ... }
```